# Broadcast listener to user touch in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to know the time left before `screen off`.
I can easily get the `timeout` defined by system, but the counter resets with each touch the user do. so I need to reset the counter on my side as well.
I don't want to have an activity in foreground but to use (probably) a `broadcastReceiver`.

Comment: found an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this but you can detect when screen off and screen on - Use actions:

```
Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON
Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF
```

But do not put it in AndroidManifest.xml you must register this broadcast, example:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){
            // screen on
        } else {
            // screen off
        }
    }
}
```

To register broadcast (do not call it in this broadcast (ScreenReceiver) - call it in Service, Activity or Application):

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
registerReceiver(new ScreenReceiver(), filter);
```

I guess the best solution is register broadcast in service because when Activity calls onDestroy() broadcast may be automatically unregistered.

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of the broadcastReceiver for screen status